# Deeplink url from email works for Windows 10 phone but not Windows 10 desktop

Tags: uwp, deep-linking, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to test a deeplink url(sample) which is set as a protocol for my UWP application. When the deeplink url(sample://test) is clicked in an email or is opened in a web browser in a phone, it works smoothly and my App gets activated, whereas when the same scenario is tried to be tested using a web browser in Windows 10 desktop the application is not getting activated, and the browser simply searches on web for that url. Also with 'Run'(Windows + R) if the url is typed, it then opens the App.

Considering it is a UWP test App, it should be consistent in both the scenarios. Is it something additional that needs to be added for Windows 10 desktop?

Comment: Are you sure that you've correctly deployed your app on local PC? I just tested with Edge, it works fine by my side.

Comment: Yes it is correctly installed, that is why with "Run", when I enter the protocol uri, it opens my app. Only envoking it from the browser is a problem.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tested Edge and Chrome, Edge works well and Chrome seems doesn't support this. I think it is related to the browser you are using.

Comment: I too am using Edge and chrome.

Comment: My OS version is 10586, what's your OS version? Maybe it's the problem with the specific OS version, or your PC test environment.

Comment: Ok, the app`s target version is 10240. Yes, I am currently troubleshooting  if it is my PC`s environment issue. I will check with changing the target version once.

Comment: I was told that Chrome can work also, just the behavior is different from Edge.